# SWF is keeping audio in sync with video

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a project that involves playing back a video clip within my swf movie. The video clip plays fine on its own, but when brought into flash the video and audio become out of sync and the movie quality suffers dramatically. I have tried embedding and streaming, but is there something I am missing?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 types of audio playback in the timeline

Stream
Event

Stream will play in sync, but Event will not... change the type by opening the frame the audio is on... select the audio and see its properties